# Dynamic number of parameters in redis.call / lua

Tags: lua, redis

i want to search by multiple MATCH from lua script, but the number of 'MATCH' depends on the script needs - i need to search for keys that match all words (in this case "aa", "bb") in any order and the number of words may be more (or less)
If its fixed its working like:

```
local result = redis.call("SCAN", 0, "MATCH", "*aa*", "MATCH", "*bb*")
```

how i can make it dynamic, where i can add as many MATCH as i need?
something like:

```
local match={}
for i=1, #ARGV do
  table.insert(match, "MATCH")
  table.insert(match, "*"..ARGV[i].."*")
end
local result = redis.call("SCAN", 0, match)
```

...i have tried to put that to string came up with error:

```
local match="SCAN 0 MATCH *aa* MATCH *bb*"
local result = redis.call(match)
```

> Unknown Redis command called from Lua script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

match in `("SCAN", 0, match)` is being passed as a table, you need to unpack this.
Something similar on these lines

```
local match={}
match[1] = "SCAN"
match[2] = 0

for i=2, #ARGV do
   match[#match+1] = "MATCH"
   match[#match+1] = "*"..ARGV[i].."*"
end

redis.call(unpack(match))
```